# How to output request headers to a string in C#

Tags: c#, api, http-headers

I would like to add two custom headers for a DELETE request to a string.

I have the following code

```
        Dictionary<string, string> customHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        customHeaders.Add("If-Match", passedEtag);
        customHeaders.Add("context_study_site", "edc42643-27b5-428e-b8ae-2fa19bfb457a");
```

I have tried the following

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + "Context headers passed in the request" + Environment.NewLine);
        Dictionary<string, string> customHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        customHeaders.Add("If-Match", passedEtag);
        customHeaders.Add("context_study_site", "edc42643-27b5-428e-b8ae-2fa19bfb457a");
        string test = customHeaders.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\Testing", "headersoutput.txt");
```

But I get the following

```
  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
```

Rather than the two header key value pairs.

Any ideas much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.ToString()` you need to `Serialize` your dictionary using `JsonConvert.SerializeObjec()`

```
var jsonDict = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( myDictionary );
```

Then write it to a file,

```
 File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Testing\headersoutput.txt", jsonDict);
```

---

Why you are getting `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.String]` in the your file?

- You are trying to convert a `Dictionary` to string using
  `.ToString()` method. You are not overriding its basic functionality,
  so it calls the basic implementation of `.ToString()` method present
  in `Object` class.

> Returns a string that represents the **current object**.

[MSDN: Basic implementation of `Object.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0)

---

How we solved it?

- We used [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) method from
  [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json.htm) library, which convert `object`(In your case
  it is a dictionary), to a json string

> Serializes the specified object to a JSON string.

Comment: @RShome, I added a detailed explanation of what I did to solve your problem. Please go through it and let me know if you any help.